# iOS: How to apply same style to another UITextField?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

Can anyone please help me, does it possible to apply the same styles(border color, border width, corner radius) from UITextField1 to UITextField2.

In Detail,
I have applied above styles to "Password" field. I wish to apply the same styles to confirm password, email, country, etc fields.

```
[[self.passwordField layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor]];
[[self.passwordField layer] setBorderWidth:0.9];
[[self.passwordField layer] setCornerRadius:5];
```

Please guide me if there is any easy way to do this, by avoiding code repeated code lines?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make one method for these code and pass textfield name to that method when you wants to use code

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys for your quick reply. I love this community :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
-(void)setTextFieldProperty:(UITextField *)myTextField{
    [[myTextField layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor]];
    [[myTextField layer] setBorderWidth:0.9];
    [[myTextField layer] setCornerRadius:5];
}
```

just call this method by:

```
[self setTextFieldProperty:mytestField]
```

it will do the rest. Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Create a collection of the views, then iterate over the collection, setting the layer properties as desired. E.g.:

```
NSArray *myTextFields = @[self.passwordField, self.emailField, self.countryField];
for (UIView *view in myTextFields){
    [[view layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor]];
    [[view layer] setBorderWidth:0.9];
    [[view layer] setCornerRadius:5];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a category on `UITextField` :

```
- (void) isPasswordField
{
    [[self layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor]];
    [[self layer] setBorderWidth:0.9];
    [[self layer] setCornerRadius:5];
}
```

And call it like this :

```
[self.passwordField isPasswordField];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. take view in which all your `UITextField` is added. Make sure this will affect all textfield of your view. you dont need to pass any textfield.

```
for (UITextField *txtFld in self.view.subviews)// set your textfield superview
{
    if ([txtFld isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
    {
        [[txtFld layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor]];
        [[txtFld layer] setBorderWidth:0.9];
        [[txtFld layer] setCornerRadius:5];
    }
}
```

Maybe this will help you.